# Using IN clause with variable scalar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make this sample working but it fails every time and displays the bad response. Can you please explain to me why that is the case? Thanks

```
DECLARE @CARACS NVARCHAR(max) = 'DLV, DLC'

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN 'DLV' IN (@CARACS) 
          THEN 'GOOD' 
          ELSE 'BAD' 
    END
```

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) You have multiple possibilites: TVP/splitting/XML/building custom query. Please choose the one that suits you best.

Comment: To answer your question, the only value that will match is `'DLV, DLC'` because that is the only choice you provided. You seem to be confused by _optimistic programming_ where you hope the code will do what you want, e.g. `7 = 'VII'`.

Comment: This is a very common mistake.
The `IN` operator expect a **list of values**, but you are supplying a **single value** that happens to contain a list

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem... DECLARE @CARACS NVARCHAR(max) = 'DLV, DLC' . 
 Only way this would work is splitting it up... because DLV will never equal 'DLV, DLC', to SQL Server 'DLV, DLC' is a single string.

```
DECLARE @CARACS1 NVARCHAR(max) = 'DLV', @CARACS2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'DLC'

SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN 'DLV' = @CARACS1 OR 'DLV' = @CARACS2
      THEN 'GOOD' 
      ELSE 'BAD' 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 queries, if you are able to find the difference between them, then you will understand why your query is returning 'Bad' value:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN 'DLV' IN ('DLV, DLC') 
          THEN 'GOOD' 
          ELSE 'BAD' END


SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN 'DLV' IN ('DLV', 'DLC') 
          THEN 'GOOD' 
          ELSE 'BAD' END
```

---

Explanation:
'DLV,DLC'  - is one value.

'DLV', 'DLC' - two values.

So, turn 'DLV,DLC' into several individual values, you need to use splitter function.

(I used Jeff Moden's splitter - DelimitedSplit8K)

```
DECLARE @CARACS VARCHAR(8000) = 'DLV,DLC'

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN 'DLV' IN (select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@CARACS,',')) 
          THEN 'GOOD' 
          ELSE 'BAD' 
    END
```